# How to send concurrent queries with dataLayer for product details and products listing?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up ecommerce tracking with Google analytics and Google Tag Manager.

One every product details page, I also have a listings - "Family products" and "Similar products".

What is the right way to send the products details and also these two listings? I'm using different dataLayer events, but does not seem to work right.

First in the code I have:

```
$(function () {
dataLayer.push({
'ecommerce': {
  'event': 'productDetailView',
  'currencyCode': 'BGN',
  'detail': {
    'products': [
      {
      'name': 'Product 1',
      'id': 'pr-1',
      'price': 19.80,
      'category': 'category / subcategory'
       }
    ]
...
});
```

And later in the code I have:

```
$(function () {
dataLayer.push({
'ecommerce': {
  'event': 'showFamilyListing',
  'currencyCode': 'BGN',
  'impressions': [
                  {
     "name": 'Product 5',
     "id": 'pr-5',
     "price": '88.10',
     'category': 'category / subcategory',
     'list': 'Family products',
     'position': 1
   },
   {

     "name": 'Product 7',
     "id": 'pr-7',
     "price": '88.10',
     'category': 'category / subcategory',
     'list': 'Family products',
     'position': 2
   },
```

And after that for the next listing:

```
$(function () {
dataLayer.push({
'ecommerce': {
  'event': 'showSimilarsListing',
  'currencyCode': 'BGN',
  'impressions': [
                  {
     "name": 'Product 19',
     "id": 'pr-19',
     "price": '18.10',
     'category': 'category / subcategory',
     'list': 'Similar products',
     'position': 1
   },
   {

     "name": 'Product 17',
     "id": 'pr-17',
     "price": '18.10',
     'category': 'category / subcategory',
     'list': 'Similar products',
     'position': 2
   },
```

It seems like only the last query is being received by Google Analytics, the products details data and the first listing are being skipped.

I have the Analytics tag set to trigger with these events (productDetailView, showFamilyListing, showSimilarsListing) and also "All pages DOM"..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only the most recent ecommerce object is included in the hit!

In other words, if you do two consecutive dataLayer.push() commands with their own ‘ecommerce’ objects, any Tag which fires after the latter push will only have access to the latter ‘ecommerce’ object.

[link](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enhanced-ecommerce-tips-and-learnings/)